# Как получить элемент в inbox mail.ru используя selenium webdriver?

Tags: python, selenium, mail.ru

Я пытаюсь получить:

```
letter_link = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("div.b-datalist__item__addr")
```

и получаю ошибку:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"div.b-datalist__item__addr"}
```

Хотя в google developer tools в DOM "div.b-datalist__item__addr" есть, но в коде страницы элемента нет. Я так понимаю что html генерируется javascriptом. В чем может быть проблема? Как мне получить ссылку на письмо, что бы кликнуть по ней?

Comment: Посмотри, как видит  страницу driver до того, как ты обращаешься к элементу. Уверен, что этот же элемент имеет другой класс, либо же его попросту ещё нет.

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, спасибо за отзыв! Я только начинаю изучать селениум и его драйвер. Я так понимаю драйвер видит скрипт, а не результат его работы, т.е. можно сказать драйверу, что бы он подождал, пока скрипты сгенерируют html а потом обращаться к классу?

Comment: Вообще, я использовал Selenium вместе с BeautifulSoup, и парсил магазины, где интерфейс на React.js
Возможно тот способ, который использовал я - не лучший или вообще не правильный, но результат мне получить удалось.

Comment: Нашёл свой старый парсер, специально сделал гист, куда выложил код. Изначально этот парсер встраивался в приложение на Flask, по этому там есть лишние импорты.

Сразу же обращу внимание на функцию def get_html(url), и вызов driver.quit() в конце. 
https://gist.github.com/narnikgamarnikus/be4c55924bd9569f4cfa90de3b512c72

Comment: @NarnikGamarnik, спасибо. Как я и думал, нужно было дождаться пока javascript сгенерирует страницу. Почему-то time.sleep(seconds) не сработал.В документации к selenium к такому способу явного ожидания относятся критически и предлагают использовать WebDriverWait из selenium.webdriver.support.ui. Что в моем случае решило проблему.

Answer (score 1):

[Ссылка на статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/273089/) на хабре про ожидания.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://somedomain/url_that_delays_loading")
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.js-href.b-datalist__item__link")))
element.click()
```